# Ambiguous type variable `p0' in the constraints

Tags: haskell

I get the error

```
Ambiguous type variable `p0' in the constraints:
      (Show p0) arising from a use of `print' at cwqr_0003.hs:31:6-10
      (Ord p0) arising from a use of `PSQ.lookup'
```

from the code below.

I have no idea how to analyze this. Could this be a problem in GHC or in one of the modules?
If I try `putStr` in place of `print` then I get an error related to the expected type being a string rather then maybe p0. When I try `fromMaybe` it gives me an error related to the default value `literal zero` that I send to fromMaybe

```
import qualified Data.PSQueue as PSQ
import Data.Maybe
import Data.Label
import Control.Category
import Prelude hiding ((.))

--some tested code omitted here 

let r = PSQ.lookup test' q
--putStr (show (r :: String)) 
print (r)
```

Comment: A very interesting thing to know would be the actual types of `test'` and `q` as this is likely where the problem lies.

Comment: But a tuple of what? (What are the types of the tuple's components?)
Also your commented-out line does not work because `PSQ.lookup` has, as its result, the type `Maybe p`, but you say that the result should be a string, which can not both be true.<br />
Further, `PSQ` is only half a type: the types of the keys and values of the `PSQ` are also part of the type.

Comment: In the future, when you give sample code, give enough that we can plug it into a compiler on our end to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message actually means exactly what it says: You have an ambiguous type. How does that happen? Usually, because you have something that produces a polymorphic result, then apply a function that takes a polymorphic argument to that result, such that the intermediate value's type is unknown.

In simple polymorphic types, the ambiguity doesn't matter: If you produce a list of something, then take the length, we don't need to know what the type of the list elements is.

If the ambiguity involves using a type class such as `Show`, however--which `print` does--GHC is stuck, because it has no way to know what instance it should pick.

Sometimes this can also arise because a particular definition is forced to be monomorphic (unless you specifically say otherwise), which forces a single type to be chosen instead of retaining the polymorphism. I suspect that might be your problem, but I can't tell without the context you've removed.

To illustrate the latter, the following definition:

```
foo = print
```

...with no type signature, causes an error like this:

```
Test.hs:12:7:
    Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
      (Show a0) arising from a use of `print'
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      foo :: a0 -> IO () (bound at Test.hs:12:1)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
    In the expression: print
    In an equation for `foo': foo = print
```

Comment: Understand, but should that not be resolved by `putStr (show (r :: String))` ? As said, this then leeds into the error w maybe since PSQ.lookup in deed returns maybe p0. If I then try to solve that with fromMaybe 0 r it gives the error related to literal zero.

Comment: @JFritsch: A type annotation would resolve the ambiguity, but that expression looks suspicious to me. `fromMaybe 0` makes me think you have a number, but you've used `String` there, and then you `show` the string, which is also strange. I'm not sure without seeing your full code, but perhaps you want something like `print (fromMaybe 0 r :: Integer)`?

Comment: Solved. print `(fromMaybe 'A' r :: String)`. It works now as intended but you are right, the whole thing is to "fishy".